# Top-bar hides cursor when scrolling up in edit-area

Tags: bug, design, top-bar

While editing a post I often enlarge the edit-area with the <sup><sup>.</sup><sub>.</sub><sup>.</sup><sub>.</sub><sup>.</sup><sub>.</sub><sup>.</sup><sub>.</sub><sup>.</sup></sup>-bar at the bottom of the edit-area. Now it may happen due to extra movements that the top of the edit-area gets hidden behind the top-bar. When I now move the cursor up towards the top-bar the cursor gets hidden behind the top-bar, too. That's somewhat irritating.

I would rather expect in this situation that the window scrolls down such that I still can see the cursor.

FF 52.0.1, Ubuntu 12.04.5